# Prevent Default behavior for Bootstrap 4 javascript scroll-spy in a rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm building a rails 5 app, and I'm attempting to add a navbar with a scrollspy to my landing page. Following the bootstrap 4 documentation, I've attached a scrollspy with javascript. However, I get a flicker sometimes when I click on one of the links in the navbar. I believe that this is due to the default behavior, and I need to call event.preventDefault() in jQuery.

I am new to jQuery and this is perhaps a really simple question, but how do I do this? In the bootstrap 4 documentation http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/scrollspy/#example-in-navbar, they mention under the javascript section that to add a scrollspy, simply do:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#myNavbar' })
```

When I wrap this in the turbolink requirements, this works just fine:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
      $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#myNavbar' })
});
```

However, I'm unsure how to pass an event to this in order prevent the flickering from happening.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768772/bootstrap-js-scrollspy-into-a-bootstrap-panel/38769208#38769208

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I submitted this an answer since it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('body').scrollspy({target: "#myNavbar"});

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("#myNavBar a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('.scrollbar,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  // End if
  });
});
```

Credit: [Bootstrap JS Scrollspy into a Bootstrap panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768772/bootstrap-js-scrollspy-into-a-bootstrap-panel/38769208#38769208)

Comment: Thank you! This helped significantly